# Does Scala compiler calls javac when compiling Java libraries imported in a Scala program?

Tags: java, scala, compilation

If I write a program in Scala and import Java libraries, does the Scala compiler calls javac (Java compiler) to compile the imported libraries to bytecode? Or is there a more obscure process, like a preliminary conversion in Scala?

Comment: What for? If the libraries are already compiled, then there simply are no `.java` files that could be converted into bytecode. A much more interesting question would have been: "what compilers are invoked in which order on what inputs when a mixed java-scala project is compiled?"

Comment: Yes, this is actually a question that could be quite useful for what I want. I would like to benefit from scala features in a java project, by making some computations "outside of the box" in scala. Do I have to open a new question or do I just edit this one for you to answer it? (I'm kind of new to asking questions on stackoverflow)

Comment: I think with an already accepted answer, it would be better to ask a new question. However, before you decide to ask the question, make sure that it is substantially different from other questions, [such as this one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247252/compilation-of-scala). The answers there also contain a lot of interesting links to articles about joint scala/java compilation.

Comment: What happened when you tested it? E.g., deleted the Java compiler or deleted the Java source files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import a library, i.e a jar on your claspath, it is already bytecode.